# How to fire an event on DOM objects dynamically generated after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, pageload

I had trouble to activate related JavaScript / jQuery event when the part of the page is loaded with dynamically created button.
How can I resolve this issue? What is the best method to resolve this issue?

It is base on my trouble in real case.

I have this function to call the php function to generate a new dynamically create pagination section in a page with Ajax.

```
function loadData(page){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ".../get_Scorewithagination.php",
            data: 'page='+page+'&testID='+testID+'&testDate='+testDate+'&empPass='+empPass+'&courseCode='+courseCode,
            success: function(msg){
                $('#testInfo').empty();
                $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){
                    loading_hide();
                    $("#resultBox").html(msg); to #resultBox
                });

                $('.iconpoint_orange').click(function() {
                    btnNames = $(this).attr("name").split("_");
                    $.post('.../getInfo.php', {testresult: btnNames[1]}, ShowTestInfo); 
                });

                // Collapse row on delete
                $('.iconpoint_blue').click(function() {
                    alert();
                    rowName = this.name;
                    rowID = '#' + rowName;
                    $(this).closest('tr').children('td').addClass("row_hover");

                    $("#dialog_confirm").html("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
                    $("#dialog_confirm").dialog({
                          buttons : {
                        "Delete" : function() { 
                        $(rowID).closest('tr').animate({opacity: 0},500).slideUp(300);
                        setTimeout(function() {$(rowID).closest('tr').empty().remove();} ,3000);
                        $(this).dialog("close");

                        },
                        "Cancel" : function() {
                        $(rowID).closest('tr').children('td').removeClass("row_hover");
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                          }
                    });
                $("#dialog_confirm").dialog("open"); // Show dialog box

                });

            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                        alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
                        $('#testInfo').html("<br\>Status: " + textStatus +"<br\>Error: " + errorThrown);
                           $('#testInfo').addClass("errorRed");


            }       

        });//$.ajax() END
    }//loadData(page) END
```

But the issue is that those two buttons

```
.iconpoint_blue
```

and

```
.iconpoint_orange
```

are not be able to call for a respond after the rows are dynamically generated by php file I called with Ajax.

I know that Ajax returned html codes are not scanned by JavaScript at the beginning of the document complete since it was completed later, therefore, the button I created dynamically will not respond to the function even its the correct selector `#`.

I want the dynamically generated button with existing function's selector for each record, will be able to call back the function that is loaded at page load?

Comment: Can you post some example code?

Comment: But can people with higher rep commenting on things you need and stop vote down just for vote down sake? This is kinda abuse of power and not friendly to new stacker as well.

Comment: For future reference, it's a good idea to post very long examples of javascript in jsFiddle so that they can be run and debugged without additional effort.

Comment: +1 because you asked a legitimate question with code and people are don't need to be jerks to new comers.

Comment: I really appreciate that OneOfOne, I wish there is more people who with high rep like you, OverStack will become a so much better environment for new people and could have been a lot more flourish. Thanks!

Comment: @OneOfOne Thats certainly true now, and I'm also upvoting, however, looking at the first version of this question the same cannot be said (I'm presuming thats when the downvotes came). Ultimately if the question was posted without the nessissary details and was downvoted, then the post was improved and the downvotes reversed then the system has worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind the function to a parent element.  For example, with this HTML:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <a href='#' class='click_here'>click here</a>
</div>
```

you could have the following javascript:

```
$('.wrapper').on( 'click', '.click_here', function() {
    $(this).after('<a href="#" class="or_here">or here</a>');
});
$('.wrapper').on( 'click', '.or_here', function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/astex/KrwxD/)'s a jsFiddle.